# Create directory of files each with a certain file size

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to create 100 files each with a file size of 10Mb. Is there a simple unix command that can create a directory with these 100 files?

Comment: FYI this is more of a question for serverFault.SE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for x in {1..100}; do dd if=/dev/zero of=file$x bs=10485760 count=1; done

if=FILE (read from FILE instead of stdin)
of=FILE (write to FILE instead of stdout)
bs=BYTES (force ibs=BYTES and obs=BYTES)
ibs=BYTES (read BYTES bytes at a time)
obs=BYTES (write BYTES bytes at a time)
count=1 (copy only 1 input block)
```

Answer (score 3):

To complements Ochi's answer, this is a way to create 100 files of 10 MB without using 1 GB of disk space and running at lightning speed:

```
size=$((10*1024*1024))
nb_files=100
for n in $(seq -f "%03.0f" 1 $nb_files); do
  dd if=/dev/zero of=file$n bs=1 count=1 seek=$((size-1))
done
```

(See [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) for more details.)

Or another way (but here, if you edit one of the files, you edit them all):

```
size=$((10*1024*1024))
n=$(seq -f "%03.0f" 1 1)
dd if=/dev/zero of=file$n bs=1 count=1 seek=$((size-1))
nb_files=100
for m in $(seq -f "%03.0f" 2 $nb_files); do
  ln file$n file$m
done
```

(See [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) for more details.)